# Regex on NSpredicate not working as expected

Tags: ios, regex, core-data, nspredicate

I'm actually totally lost trying to use a regex into a NSpredicate. 
What i want is a regex who find all the beginning of words in a sentence who match criteria. The fact is that doesn't work.

Here's my regex: `.*\b xxx [\w-]*` (where xxx is my criteria).

And here's the code

```
   NSString* regexString   = [NSString stringWithFormat: @".*\\b%@[\\w-]*", search];
   request.predicate       = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"adresse matches[cd] %@", regexString];
```

adress are a string property of my core data object. But for some obscure reason, that doesn't work. Can someone help me?

For example: 
CITY SANDWITCH 67200 STRASBOURG

`.*\bStra[\w-]*` will find STRASBOURG

but `.*\b672[\w-]*` or `.*\bSAND[\w-]*` will result nothing.

**edit**

I finally give up and wrote `(adresse BEGINSWITH[c] %@) OR (adresse CONTAINS[c] %@)` statement instead, where %@ is the search word term.

But the topic is still open if someone can explain me why simple regex formula in obj-c seems  like lauching a rocket in space. What is strange is the regex actually works, but half the way it should be, like if the rule wasn't strictly followed. I'm really confused now.

Comment: Hi there, your pattern seems a bit strange to me (I am quite new to regex) but why do you have a `-` at the end ? are you expecting any `-` in your string ?

Comment: The fact is when i text the regex on webSite, that work fine. I even wrote the \b[\w] regex on Java code and it works well. But on iOS I dunno why, that really not working at all. So i'm actually lost and use extra rules like .* at the beginning and * at the end, or the regex is not working at all

Comment: I posted an anwser using something quite similar to java's way to do it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use the same object as you did but another that I understand a bit more and that looks more like Java's one ;)

```
NSString* string = @"CITY SANDWITCH 67200 STRASBOURG";
NSString* search = @"SAND"; // work also with 672 or STRAS
NSString* regexString  = [NSString stringWithFormat: @".*\\b(%@[\\w]*)[\\s*\\w*]*", search];
NSError  *error  = NULL;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:regexString
                              options:0
                              error:&error];

NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@"$1"];

NSLog(@"-->%@", modifiedString);
```

Comment: The OP seems to want to use `NSPredicate` and also wants to search for "Sand", not "SAND".

Comment: Yeah I saw that but prefer to give an answer working even if it's not in `NSPredicate` :) I don't know so much about `NSPredicate` so I let other answer on this ;)

Comment: Ok thanks all for the solution. And both Clad Clad and @Akhilrajtr solution works fine. What I don't understand is where to find the correct documentation for those kind of regex, since they don't seems to follow the same rules. But When i read tuto, they talk as if all regex where totally standard.

Comment: Personally I went on : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html and http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html which are pretty good documentation (for IOS first link/ Java second link)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `regexString` to

```
NSString* regexString   = [NSString stringWithFormat: @".*\\b%@.*", search];
```